# Set custom time for window.performance mark

Tags: javascript

I have a scenario in which I would like to be able to set a mark with a custom time in the [window.performance API.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance)

Some event occurs at time X but the name of that event is not known until a later time.

I was hoping to be able to do something like this:

```
function markAwait() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var timeStamp = $window.performance.now();
    deferred.promise.then(function(markName) {
        $window.performance.mark(markName, timeStamp);
    });
    return deferred;
}

var deferredMark = markAwait();

// Do some things which take time

deferredMark.resolve('myMarkName');
```

Unfortunately, you cannot call performance.mark() in this way. My next idea was to just try to create a Mark object and write it to the performance mark array directly. I wasn't having any luck with this approach.

Is there a way to to accomplish what I'm looking for?

Comment: Maybe you could use measure instead of mark..  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/measure

Comment: Note, `performance.mark()` expects one parameter to be passed [PerformanceMark](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceMark) _"The method takes one argument, the name of the mark"_

Answer (score 0):

Set the `mark` first, then iterate `.getEntriesByType()` with `"mark"` as parameter, check if `name` is equal to name passed to `resolve()` call, then subtract `window.performance.now()` from `mark.startTime`

```
function markAwait() {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  $window.performance.mark("defer");
  deferred.promise.then(function(markName) {
    var entries = $window.performance.getEntriesByType("mark");
    for (var entry of entries) {
      if (entry.name === markName) {
        console.log(window.performance.now() - entry.startTime)
      }
    }
  });
  return deferred;
}

var deferredMark = markAwait();

// Do some things which take time

  deferredMark.resolve("defer");
```

```js
function markAwait() {
  var deferred = $.Deferred();
  window.performance.mark("defer");
  deferred.promise().then(function(markName) {
    var entries = window.performance.getEntriesByType("mark");
    for (let entry of entries) {
      if (entry.name === markName) {
        console.log(window.performance.now() - entry.startTime)
      }
    }
  });
  return deferred;
}

var deferredMark = markAwait();

// Do some things which take time
deferredMark.resolve("defer");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```